# Como usar uma pagina html como input no opencv python?

Tags: python, opencv

Preciso colocar uma página em html em sobreposição a minha câmera usando OpenCV (Python), mas não sei como poderia fazer isso.
Consegui fazer algo parecido com esse código:

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('http:/192.168.0.100:8080/video')

while True:

    ret, frame=cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('Frame',frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Mas esse código só funciona com um stream de vídeo, precisava utilizar em uma  página html comum, como se fosse um "browser source" do OBS studio.

Alguém poderia me orientar se é possível fazer isso?

Comment: Ta usando o app droidcam?

Comment: Usei o "IP webcam" pra fazer esse teste, mas eu precisava fazer o mesmo só que com uma página HTML comum, como a página do Google por exemplo.